# Making a block of X's with a number

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to have the user enter a number and have the computer output a square with side of that number.

For example:

```
Enter a number:
4

XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
XXXX
```

I got this far, but don't know what else to do:

```
package blockmaker;
import java.util.*;

public class BlockMaker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        int number = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            System.out.println("X");
        }
    }

}
```

My current code outputs:

```
Enter a number: 
4
X
X
X
X
```

Do I need to put a loop inside a loop?

Comment: Yes. You need a nested loop.

Comment: I wonder why this question has been downvoted. It may be basic programming, but the questing is well asked and it shows some effort towards a solution. +1 from me, to make up for this unfair downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need an inner loop for that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            System.out.println("X"); // print X and new line
}
```

Above code prints "X" in each line.
Instead you need to print "X" `number(n)` times in each line. You need a nested loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < number; j++)
        System.out.print("X"); // print X - n times
    System.out.println(); // print new line
}
```